# Looping Through Two Cells To Find Matches, And then Copying Range When There's A Match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a google app sctipt that loops through to ranges of dates to find matches, and for every match it finds, it copies specified range of "expenses" into a specified range. When I run the script, it executes, but nothing happens. It exceed execution time limit so I think it's getting stuck in a loop.

UPDATE: I've created a test worksheet if anyone would like to see an example of the data involved: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J9L5b3UMCJGZV8QiUu9RyVrmaDVaK7FroLN8aDLYwxs/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```
function menuItem1() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Updating Expenses 2
  for(row = 10; row <= 61; row++){
    var date1 = sheet.getRange(row, 3, 1);
    var date1value = date1.getValue();

    for(row2 = 22; row2 < 59; row++){
      var date2 = sheet.getRange(row2, 18, 1);
      var date2value = date2.getValue();


      if(date1value == date2value){
        sheet.getRange(row2, 19, 2, 8).copyTo(sheet.getRange(row1, 5, 8), {contentsOnly:true});
      }
    }
```

If anyone could help in anyway to figure out what the issue is, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation about [best practice in spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) to try to speed up your code.

Below is a strict translation of your code that will execute in less than a second while doing exactly the same thing.  Once you get rid of the timeout issue I hope you will be able to make it do what you want.

Of course I didn't test the final goal of your script because I've no idea about your data.

A couple of variables are dates, in that case you should pay special attention to it and see if dates have eventually an associated time value that you don't see in the sheet and handle that as well.

code :

```
function menuItem1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();// get all values in your sheet up to the last row and last column (where data exist)
  // define limits in array (values = row values-1)
  var r1start = 9;
  var r1max = 60;
  var r2start = 21;
  var r2max = 58;
  // choose columns
  var col1 = 2; 
  var col2 = 17;
  for(var r1=r1start ;  r1<r1max ; r1++){
    for(var r2=r2start ;  r2<r2max ; r2++){
      if(data[r1][col1] == data[r2][col2]){
        sheet.getRange(r2+1, 19, 2, 8).copyTo(sheet.getRange(r1+1, 5, 8), {contentsOnly:true});
        Logger.log('match found');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### EDIT :

The code above was working but it didn't take into account all the empty cells so it found plenty of matches on empty cells. The comparison on date object was not working right, that's why I switched to native date values ( milliseconds)...
Since it copies values only we didn't see the data changes, it was writing empty values all over the destination range!

Now it is much easier to get it right with the example sheet    : -) , new working code below.

```
function menuItem1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();// get all values in your sheet up to the last row and last column (where data exist)

  // define limits in array (values = row values-1)
  var r1start = 9;
  var r1max = 60;
  var r2start = 21;
  var r2max = 58;

  // choose columns
  var col1 = 2; 
  var col2 = 17;

  for(var r1=r1start ;  r1<r1max ; r1++){
    for(var r2=r2start ;  r2<r2max ; r2++){
      if(data[r1][col1]=='' || data[r2][col2]==''){continue}; // skip all empty rows to avoid false equalities in empty cells and speed up the process
      Logger.log(data[r1][col1]+'  = ?  '+data[r2][col2]);// this is only to view data in the logger
      if(data[r1][col1].getTime() == data[r2][col2].getTime() ){ // compare on date native values
        sheet.getRange(r2+1, 19, 2, 8).copyTo(sheet.getRange(r1+1, 5, 8), {contentsOnly:true});
        Logger.log('match found'); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know about best practices. I'll definitely be reading through that. But as for the code you provided, it definitely solved the exceeding execution time limit, but it didn't successfully copy the data over and I'm not sure why... I've created a test worksheet if you'd like to get a look at the data. Added the link above. As you will see, there are corresponding dates, but the matching dates don'd result in the data on the right side of the sheet being copied to the corresponding left dates.

Comment: Thanks for the sheet copy... much easier  now ;-)

Comment: btw, when you give a link to a shared sheet you should share it in "view only" (and force people to make a copy to test) to avoid some users to fill your sheet with various garbage ;-) (I learned from experience !!, you can't trust people even here ;-)

Comment: I allowed myself to change the sharing properties... I hope you won't mind ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much Serge (and duly noted about sharing in the future, lol). This worked perfectly! You rock!